# Remote Database using Tinywebdb in app inventor 2?

Tags: php, app-inventor

I am trying to connect to my remote database, I have already created my api on the server (PHP) where the link : mydomain.com/myapi.php?myrequest=Login is the service url

this service requires a json array like the following {"email":"myemail@something.com", "password":"mypass"}.. those 2 values must be passed through MIT app inventor 2 with a 2 texboxes and then when the user click on the button login then I will show a success message on a label.

My service returns false in case there was something wrong in the authentication.

In the MIT app inventor 2 I am specifying my url service as a property (mydomain.com/myapi.php?myrequest=Login) for the tinywebdb but how can I get a result from my api?

in the server side I am using `sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));` to get the result from my api.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is how to do the authentication in MIT app with a remote db that I created

Comment: I wanna tell my tinywebdb that I have email and password that I wanna pass with the request, it seems that I only can set the service url

Comment: use the `web` component instead of `TinyWebDB`, see some examples here https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#web. In case it is a MySQL database, see this example https://puravidaapps.com/mysql.php